# get the repeated list values of a dictionary and make an increment

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

1.Input dataframe:

```
ID emp
1  a
2  b
3  a
```

Dictionary created with additional key(occ) value:

I have made a main_dict with complete data and sub_dict with each seperate unique keys.

**expected result**

```
main_dict= {'1' : ['a'], '2' : ['b'], '3' : ['a'], occ: 1}

sub_dict1 = {'1' : ['a'], occ: 2}
sub_dict2 = {'2' : ['b'], occ: 1}
sub_dict3 = {'3' : ['a'], occ: 1}
```

2.If I add another row example

```
ID emp
1  a
2  b
3  a
4  a
```

**expected result-2**

```
main_dict= {'1' : ['a'], '2' : ['b'], '3' : ['a'], '4' : ['a'], occ: 1}

sub_dict1 = {'1' : ['a'], occ: 3}
sub_dict2 = {'2' : ['b'], occ: 1}
sub_dict3 = {'3' : ['a'], occ: 1}
sub_dict4 = {'4' : ['a'], occ: 1}
```

**problem**: How do I make the occ functionality working as per the value of emp.
I want that when ever the value(emp) of each Id is same then the occ value should increment 1 and for rest it should stay same.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please elaborate.

Comment: hope its clear now.

Comment: Why is "occ" of `'1' : ['a']` equal to 2?

Comment: it is the incremented value,
i have updated it.
it is dependent on emp value